# How to show the name of file equal to the height and widh input

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap 4, my problem is when i put a file with a long name , the name will go out of the input

[image]

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Edit the question, and show the code you've attempted..

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you could supply a code sample, but essentially you will need to set the size - `height` and `width` on your `input` and use `overflow:hidden` on it.

EDIT: Since you're using the Bootstrap 4 and their input file implementation, assuming your HTML is as provided in their example:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

and you're appending the name to .custom-file-label element with JS, as per their documentation, you will then have to set overflow hidden to your label:

```
.custom-file-label {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/frked93u/7/

If you need a more elegant solution to this, I would recommend using overflow ellipsis and additional padding on the label, so instead of cutting mid-text it is going to just append ellipsis in the end of the filename, when  the label runs out of space.

```
.custom-file-label {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-right:75px;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/frked93u/9/

In the future you will receive help much faster and more accurately, if you update your question with code samples and/or working fiddle, instead of just providing details about the framework you're using.

Comment: Using overflow ellipsis worked for me

Answer (score -2):

Reduce the lenght of Name, like

```
fileName=fileName.substring(0, 10);
```